# Created date between that particular month mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, group-by

I have a table `event`, where i have records with a field `end_date`, so my problem is i want to fetch number of records, grouping month wise, where `end_date` should with in that month only, so for example:

If a record have `end_date` as `2013-01-01 00:00:00` then it should be counted in `January 2013`, and i am not able to do that. I am unable to put that where condition, how to do tell database that `end_date` should be between the month for which it is currently grouping.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count', MONTH(created) AS 'month', YEAR(created) AS 'year' FROM event WHERE is_approved =1 GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created)
```

Please help me out.

**EDIT :**

Data say i have is like:

```
 Record name  end_date
 record_1     2013-11-01 00:00:00
 record_2     2013-11-30 00:00:00
 record_3     2013-12-01 00:00:00
 record_4     2013-12-04 00:00:00
 record_5     2013-12-06 00:00:00
 record_6     2013-12-10 00:00:00
 ...many more
```

Result Expected is:

```
 Count    month  year
  2         11   2013
  4         12   2013
  ....so on
```

Comment: `... where .... and month(created) = 1 and year(created) = 2013 group by ...`

Comment: I have data for each month, Jan was just an example..

Comment: please paste some sample data and expected output

Comment: @saveATcode: Then your select query should work resulting record count per month. Post your sample data from table and your expected output from them.

Comment: Updated the result expected and records i have

Comment: Yes i want my query to output count per month, thats what i exactly need and specific in question..

Comment: I made a query which produces the result like example you have given but i am confused about "i need something like > that particular month for which we are grouping" can u explain this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'count', MONTH(end_date) AS 'month', YEAR(end_date) AS 'year' 
FROM event 
WHERE is_approved = 1 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM end_date);
```

**OR**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'count', MONTH(end_date) AS 'month', YEAR(end_date) AS 'year' 
FROM event 
WHERE is_approved = 1 
GROUP BY YEAR(end_date), MONTH(end_date);
```

**::EDIT::**

**1. end date is greater than that particular month** - Simply add where condition in your query and pass particular month in format of **YYYYMM** instead of **201411**

**2. event is started** - Add one more where condition to check whether the **created** date is less then current date

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'count', MONTH(end_date) AS 'month', YEAR(end_date) AS 'year' 
FROM event 
WHERE is_approved = 1 AND 
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM end_date) > 201411 AND 
      DATE(created) <= CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM end_date);
```

**OR**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'count', MONTH(end_date) AS 'month', YEAR(end_date) AS 'year' 
FROM event 
WHERE is_approved = 1 AND 
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM end_date) > 201411 AND 
      DATE(created) <= CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY YEAR(end_date), MONTH(end_date);
```

Comment: what if i want to count all of the records where end date is greater than that particular month, and also the event is started??

Comment: @saveATcode If you want to check for end date is greater than that particular month then add where clause with `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM end_date) > 201411` And what is the field you are using for checking of event is started or not.  Check my updated answer...

Comment: The problem is i have records for 52 months i can't run query one by one for each months. Need a generic solution, so instead of defining > 201411, i need something like > that particular month for which we are grouping..

Comment: i am using `created` for checking started or not.

Comment: @saveATcode It is dynamic pass only the particular month instead of that. i.e. if you want to find data from January 2014 then pass 201401 it will give you data after january 2014 with grouping

Comment: @saveATcode For started flag check my updated query. add where clause as `AND DATE(created) <= CURRENT_DATE()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67519/discussion-between-saharsh-shah-and-saveatcode).

Answer (score 1):

The count is aggregated based on the month and year so if you are spanning years, you wont have Jan 2013 mixed with Jan 2014, hence pulling those values too and that is the same basis of the group by.

As for your criteria, that all goes in the WHERE clause.  In this case, I did anything starting with Jan 1, 2013 and ending Dec 31, 2014 via 'yyyy-mm-dd' standard date recognized format.  That said, and the structure of the table you provided, I am using the "end_date" column.

```
SELECT 
      YEAR(end_date) AS EventYear,
      MONTH(end_Date) AS EventMonth, 
      COUNT(*) AS EventCount
   FROM 
      event 
   WHERE is_approved = 1 
     and end_date between '2013-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
   GROUP BY 
      YEAR(end_date),
      MONTH(end_Date)
```

Now, if you want them to have the most recent events on the top, I would put the year and month descending so 2014 is listed first, then 2013, etc and months within them as December (month 12), before the others.

```
   GROUP BY 
      YEAR(end_date) DESC,
      MONTH(end_Date) DESC
```

Your criteria could be almost anything from as simple as just a date change, approved status, or even get counts per account status is so needed, such as (and these are just EXAMPLES if you had such code status values)

```
      SUM( is_approved = 0 ) as PendingEvent,
      SUM( is_approved = 1 ) as ApprovedEvent,
      SUM( is_approved = 2 ) as CancelledEvent
```

Per comment feedback.

For different date ranges, ignore the between clause and change the WHERE to something like

```
WHERE end_date > '2014-08-01'  or all after a date... 
where end_date < '2014-01-01'  or all before a date...
```

They will still group by month / year.  If you wanted based on a start date of the event, just change that column in instead, or do IN ADDITION to the others.

Comment: what if i want to count all of the records where end date is greater than that particular month, and also the event is started??

Comment: @saveATcode, revised bottom of answer to clarify WHERE clause adjustments.

Comment: @saveATcode, just checking... have any of the answers worked for your solution?  You can always accept an answer before the end of a bounty period.  It helps to know what really worked for your solution vs just the one with the most votes... and that goes for any other question out here... best for the user for future of others with similar problems what worked vs not.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a bunch of [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that can help you with that. For example:

> `MONTH()` Return the month from the date passed

or

> `YEAR()`  Return the year

So you can just get the month and year of your dates. And group your results by them.

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*) cnt
    ,MONTH(end_date) month
    ,YEAR(end_date) year
FROM events
GROUP BY month, year
```

Result :

```
cnt     month   year
2       11      2013
4       12      2013
```

**Update:**

For filtering only the records that have an `end_date` greater than a particular month AND have already started, you just need to add a `WHERE` clause. For example, if the particular month were February 2015:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*) cnt
    ,MONTH(end_date) month
    ,YEAR(end_date) year
FROM events
WHERE end_date >= '2015-03-01'
    AND created < NOW()
GROUP BY month, year
```

Alternatively, the first part of the `WHERE` clause can be rewritten in the following way, which is probably more comfortable to use if you have to pass the year and month as distinct parameters.

```
...
WHERE (YEAR(end_date) > 2015
    OR (YEAR(end_date) = 2015 AND MONTH(end_date) > 02))
    AND created...
```

Comment: what if i want to count all of the records where end date is greater than that particular month, and also the event is started??

Comment: @saveATcode I updated the answer. However, I suggest you edit your original question with any additional requirements you have, rather than expressing them in comments (given that the requirements are not independent enough to merit a separate question).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count', MONTH(created) AS 'month', YEAR(created) AS 'year' FROM event WHERE is_approved =1 and month(created) = "the month u want" and year(created) = "the year you want" group by GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created)
```

you will need to pull the month and year... i could help with that but not sure how you are getting it but months would be 01/02/03 ect and year is 2013/2014/2015 ect

Comment: You pasted group by twice. And it doesn't help, please see my edit.